# Of 2n people, n are male, and n are female, in how many ways can they be split into two equal groups such that there is atleast one girl in each group

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am having a struggle trying to get my head around the choose function in discrete mathematics, for this question I understand given the groups are indistinguishable there are ${2n \choose n}/2!$ ways to arrange them into two equal groups. But am struggling with contemplating how I can put restraints such as having a minimum of 1 girl into each group into a general formula, let alone with actual numerical values. I would much appreciate any help!

Comment: Well...how many divisions violate the constraint?

Comment: Is it the case where all of the girls are in one group, and all of the boys are in the other? If so, would this be ((2nCn)/2)-1?

Comment: Yep, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the response and help, here is my solution. Given the two groups are indistinguishable, there are $${2n \choose n}/2!$$ ways to arrange 2n people, n being male and n being female, into two indistinguishable groups. There is only one case where the constraint is violated, that would be that one team was fully girls and the other was fully boys. Hence the final answer is, $${2n \choose n}/2! - 1$$